# Localhost blank page PHP

Tags: php, apache, xampp

When i open my created Program.php(

```
<<?php echo "Hello World!" ?>
```

) file, then the "http://localhost/Program.php" page doesn't show the "Hello World" output. It just shows a blank page.

When i look in the sourcecode of the page, then it shows me

```
<Hello World!
```

Also when i run C:\xampp\php\php-cgi.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\Program.php in the command prompt, then it shows me the same output `<Hello World!"`

When i open the "http://localhost/" then it shows me the welcome page of xampp.

"http://Localhost\phpinfo.php" send back 404 not found.

Please help to fix this issue

Comment: We'd need to see your code. The output you get (which isn't valid HTML) suggests you have imbalanced angle-brackets somewhere, but it really could be all sorts of things that we can't possibly guess at.

Comment: You can't use backslash in URLs, it has to be forward slashes.

Comment: Remember that when you "view source" in your browser, you're not seeing the PHP source, you're seeing the output from it.

Comment: Where is code??? `Localhost\phpinfo.php` ???? `http://localhost/test/test.php`

Comment: `<<?php` should be `<?php`. Always double check your work carefully. And yes for a URL you must use / not \

Comment: `<Hello World!` is an invalid HTML tag. Browsers are designed to recover from errors rather than just crashing. The fix for invalid tags is to ignore them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Program.php**, you have extra `<` sign in front

```
<<?php echo "Hello World!" ?>
```

try:

```
<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>
```

Regarding **phpinfo.php**

**404** genereally means page not found. So make sure that file exists at root of your server.

If your server runs at: `/var/www` then your file path should be `/var/www/phpinfo.php`

Comment: Please share more details. How does your hint resolve the 404 error?

Comment: @NicoHaase made an edit.

Comment: Thanks, this worked fine.
That was the autocomplete of atom o.O

Im working with xampp on windows 10.
Path is:
"C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\phpinfo.php"